# Complexity of Deciding if a Variety is non-empty

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algorithms, computational-complexity

I am having difficulty finding the right sources/papers to look through for the complexity class of deciding if a Variety over C is non-empty.

I can show that saying a Variety is empty is in NP, since one can compute a Grobner basis and check if it's 1, then the verifier simply takes as input the summation showing that 1 is in the ideal.

But I can't find results for the complexity class of the complement problem. I can reduce the problem to finding a $\bar{Q}$-rational point in the algebraic variety, since to confirm it all we have to do is have a point which we can do polynomial-time computations with and confirm that it is in the variety. However, finding rational points seems difficult from my cursory look through the Wikipedia page. Along these lines, I have heard that numerical algebraic geometry has a method of sampling points (randomly?) in variety - maybe this would help me? But I don't understand that process.

In *Solving polynomial equations; Foundations, algorithms, and applications* the authors state on pg. 260

[image]

Algebraic variety seems to be the standard definition of a variety in affine space, and encoded in dense form is defined in a previous section and simply needs that our polynomials are of bounded degree. This seems really powerful, but the original paper is in French and I can't read French. Maybe someone more familiar with this subject could help me make sure I understand this result correctly?

Here is a link to the GH93 paper:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266404905_La_d_etermination_des_points_isol_es_et_de_la_dimension_d'une_vari_et_e_alg_ebrique_peut_se_faire_en_temps_polynomial?fbclid=IwAR0Ovgg0toTcuexnNIyCvETd1tiJvgIYqoJuEewuz8xxcty_Qof6_ftJxuI

Comment: Oh also I could compute a grobner basis and see that it is not {1} but then I run into the issue that confirming it is a Grobner basis is not polynomial because the number of terms is not polynomial. 

Also dense encoding seems to be not an issue as it is defined in 6.3 of the book and only requires that the polynomials have bounded degree.